# Exiting scanf with less arguments then specified

Tags: c, scanf

I have a problem with scanf. I wrote a little calculator program, but now i want to exit the calculator when i input a single 0.

```
 int main(void) {
     int first;
     char operation;
     int second;
     while(1) {
        int correct = scanf("%d %c %d", &first, &operation, &second);
        if(first == 0 && correct == 1) return(0);
     }
 return 0;
 }
```

My code isn't working, because scanf waits until it typed 3 things. Can I exit scanf, when only one single 0 is typed?

Comment: It is operating system specific. On Linux, you probably can force an end-of-file with Ctrl D...

Comment: Why not have three `scanfs`?

Comment: Because i want a single line input.

Comment: `fgets` --> check "0\n" --> `sscanf`

Comment: Additionally to what Basile's said, you can do a search for _buffering_, especially that `stdin` is usually line-buffered. And `first` should be read only if something has been assigned to it, that is, _after_ you've checked `correct` is at least 1.

Comment: Regarding your last comment: `scanf` isn't line-oriented. Normally (that is, outside `%[]` scansets) newline isn't treated differently than other whitespace characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the user input line and then scan it.

```
#include <limits.h>
// First determine a buffer large enough for reasonable worst case input
// S_SIZE_INT is big enough for INT_MIN
#define S_SIZE_INT (sizeof int * CHAR_BIT/3 + 3)
#define S_SIZE_INT_CHAR_INT (S_SIZE_INT*2 + 1 + 3 /*sep*/ +2 /*eol*/ +10 /*CYA*/)

int main(void) {

  int first;
  char operation;
  int second;

   while (1) {
     char buf[S_SIZE_INT_CHAR_INT];           
     if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) {
       break; // EOF detected
     } 
     int correct = sscanf(buf, "%d %c %d", &first, &operation, &second);

     // Best to test `correct` before testing `first` to know something was read
     // As commented by @mafso
     if (correct == 1 && first == 0) return(0);

   }
 return 0;
 }
```